# How to resolve error while installing ChromeDriverManager in Airflow Docker?

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, airflow, webdriver-manager

I am facing error while getting latest version of google-chrome. I have added the following necessary PYPI packages in docker.yaml file.

1. selenium, 2. webdriver-manager, 3. chromedriver_autoinstaller, 4. chromedriver-py, 5. chromedriver, 6. webdriver_manager

**Here is my code.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--download-path=/opt/airflow')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')

chrome_service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
```

**This is the error I'm getting.**

```
chrome_service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url
    driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install chrome to your operating system, it can't find the driver because chrome has not been installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).